# Automate excel reconciliation

Tags: python, excel

I’m looking for a good video/article explaining how to automate tasks on excel thanks to python.

E.g.: retrieving data from a sql data base then doing some reconciliation within excel automatically

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just watch some videos. It is easy to learn. Good luck.

[https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=python+excel](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=python%20excel)

[https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=python+sqlite](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=python%20sqlite)